# Final initialization error in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a final and I am trying initializing that in the constructor. It is giving me error & If I don't make it final I get a warning.

> This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: GenderCard.genderSvg",

My Code:

```
  GenderCard({@required this.genderType}) {
    genderSvg = '/assets/' + 'genderType' + '.svg';
  }
  final String genderType;
  final String genderSvg;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`final` instance variables must be initialized in the initializer list. See the [language guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const).

> Instance variables can be final but not const. Final instance
>   variables must be initialized before the constructor body starts — at
>   the variable declaration, by a constructor parameter, or in the
>   constructor’s initializer list.

Change your constructor to:

```
class GenderCard {
  GenderCard({@required this.genderType})
      : genderSvg = '/assets/$genderType.svg';

  final String genderType;
  final String genderSvg;
}
```